# Cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 class

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, android-flexboxlayout

I am having runtime problems with my gradle file. I added this `compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.1'` as a compile time dependency to my Gradle file. I encountered an error and added this in my project level Gradle file.

```
maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
```

Which finally looked liked this after adding the above

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

After adding the above in my app level Gradle file I am now encountering a different error when I am trying to run my app. So I did the following as per some answers from SO.

1. Tried a Clean and Rebuild.
2. Navigated to the path `projectName\.idea\libraries` and deleted the files that contained the support library version other than the current versions `25.3.1`
   3.In order to solve the error I further removed this line from my app level Gradle file,

   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
       })

Now the final Gradle file looks like this with the error,

Error:

```
Error:(28, 8) error: cannot access ActivityCompatApi23
class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found
```

My Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared `compileSdkVersion` equal to 25, whereas `0.3.1` version of flexbox layout [uses](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/blob/master/build.gradle#L29) support libs version `26.0.0` - that's a problem, `compileSdkVersion` should match support libs major version.

Either upgrade your project to 26 or use a version of flexbox layout that relies on sdk 25, which seems to be v0.2.7:

```
compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.7'
```

Comment: Let me check that..From where did you get this information ? It was not there in the official Github readme file

Comment: `From where did you get this information?` which one?

Comment: `whereas 0.3.1 version of flexbox layout uses support libs version 26.0.0` this one

Comment: You can click on the *"uses"* word, which is an url to the source code.

Answer (score 5):

Like the Problem I meet。

When I Use  Android Room like this :

compileSdkVersion  25
 compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"

I  get the same Error.

Because compileSdkVersion should match support libs major version.

More Detail you can see this ：
[Error in support lib after room persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47734482/error-in-support-lib-after-room-persistence)

> Room depends on 26.1 of support library, which is probably why it is broken because SupportLibrary does not promise interop between versions.

Also， you can fix the problem use this

```html
compile ("android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0") {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the line

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

to 
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'`

and it worked for me